# Typing a function that wraps any argument in to an array

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to properly type a function that takes an argument and wraps it into an array, however, I can't get the typings to work properly.

```
function wrapInArray<T>(data:T):T extends Array<infer K>? K[]: T[]{
  
  return Array.isArray(data)? [...data]:[data] 
  // ^ Type '(T & any[])[number][]' is not assignable to type 'T extends (infer K)[] ? K[] : T[]'
}

const a = wrapInArray('test') // string[]

const b = wrapInArray([1,2]) // number[]
```

The function works correctly, and if I try to use the function, typescript correctly infers the return type. Now I'm wondering why I'm getting an error in the function declaration itself.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOBJMBBVDATwB4AVAPgAoATdKdALjIEpnEBTADyg7BoDOiAsRIwwwDqkQBpCgH5ZAbQC6jRGVUBvALAAoRIn2HUHKCFRIR6IgDoYA60Vr10LRUtte6DNUp-oKkYGiAD0oYgAehpEmByIAORUZIgAZIjoYESqLEpgIAC2AEZSKqoJiA6IYHBQGQICMADmYOhFADbxUHCIULHxCSncvPxCVOKS0jK5QYoyqojqmioJ+gC++voQCAJ16IgAvCgYOPiENlQJvLsJLGERu6jiTaqbettgu4hFh8dYuE4qEoAIwAGgATCo7uFqoUSqhVEA)

Comment: Conditional type for return type does not play well. I think an overloading is the best option here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the nature of the isArray function. It's typed like this:

```
isArray(arg: any): arg is any[];
```

So when it's true, the `arg is any[]` says that data is `any[]` but you also said it was `T` so you end up with `T & any[]`...

How about (no need for overloading and bonus, we don't have to specify what the function returns, we'll let Typescript infer that for us):

```
function wrapInArray<T>(data: T | T[]){ //function wrapInArray<T>(data: T | T[]): T[]
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    // (parameter) data: T[]
    // T was either T | T[] but it's an array, we're left with only T[]
    return [...data]
  } else {
    // (parameter) data: T
    // data was either T | T[] but it's not an array so we're left with T
    return [data] // we return [T]
  }
}

const a = wrapInArray('test') // string[]

const b = wrapInArray([1,2]) // number[]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOBJMBBVDATwB4AVAPgAoATdKdALkTMQB8WBtAXQEoBvRAHohoSLAQoMOfIXSlKtekxbsufZmR4BYAFCJEMYIioFiAOhgBnM-KUNevRPz0GDqAKZQQqJJ3MBdAzcrogAvogeADZWHs6h7l4%20fkHoIfrhemF6ehAIVlCI6IgAvFJYuLZEVADkUB4FNU4iiAWoMGAA5jq6ufmFAEal5TJVVJwAjAA0AEx8wkKIYCAAtgMeqDxAA)

Comment: I like your answer more than mine. Well done :) You have my upvote.

Comment: Nice and simple thanks, nice catch about `isArray` typings.

Answer (score 2):

You can try function [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```js
function wrapInArray<T extends any[]>(data: T): T;
function wrapInArray<T>(data: T): T[];
function wrapInArray<T>(data: T):T | T[]{
  return Array.isArray(data)? [...data]:[data] 
}

const a = wrapInArray('test') // string[]

const b = wrapInArray([1,2]) // number[]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOBJMBBVDATwB4AVRAUwA8pKwATAZ0XTCIG0BdAPgAoG6KOgBciMgEoxZANwBYAFChIsBCgw58hdKTL9Bw6VPHd5S8NHhI0WXAWLl9Q0eKkUAPia4BvRYkSolFAgqEj2OgB0MEzhRALOEgD8iBwRaQboXCIcGVyIigC+iooQCExQrIgAvOq2WsR8AOR05Y0SiAD0HYjlqDBgAObcxQqlYOWIAEbVtZqxfBwAjAA0AExc7V2IYCAAtpOUqNxAA)